# D3 tooltip or mouseover on bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

```
    var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate("+barWidth*i+",0)";
    })
.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("fill", "red");
})
.on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("fill", "blue");
});
```

I am trying to do a mouseover to show data. I am starting by trying to change the colour on a mouseover as per code above.

http://codepen.io/JohnnyBizzel/pen/xqbjVQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZrZRP)

A couple of things wrong here:

1. You are trying to apply the transition to the `g` and not the `rect`
2. Instead of `attr` you want to use `style`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this).select('rect').style('fill', 'red');
})
.on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).select('rect').style('fill', 'blue');
});
```

You need to select the shape that is into your element and his style function to change the color.